# How to set StrictHostKeyChecking to no in Azure CLI bash window for ssh_config

Tags: linux, bash, azure, ssh, azure-virtual-machine

I want to edit `StrictHostKeyChecking` value to `no` from `ask`.

I have gone through online. Many suggested to use `vi` or `nano` commands and edit value but I'm not  aware of vi or nano .

Is there any single line command which can be used to edit `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no`.

I want to  edit in `Azure CLI bash` command prompt https://shell.azure.com/bash .

Please suggest.

**Update 1:**

below command throwing errors.

```
Host *
  StrictHostKeyChecking  no
```

[image]

How to use above command.

**Update 2:**

Finally I set `StrictHostKeyChecking`  to `no` for `Host *`

When I try to connect to remote azure linux vm from powershell , I still get below error.

> Host key verification failed for '10.20.30.40':fingerprint
>   SHA256:mssgkeghbfnb9883yygebwndjhk is unknown for '10.20.30.40'

How to resolve it.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It worked.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your requirements that in Azure Cloud Shell to SSH to the VM and set the property `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no`. You can use the code edit in Cloud Shell like this:

[image]

Use this way to set the SSH config file(if it does not exist, just create it) as the screenshot shows. All these steps should be done in the bash window, not in PowerShell, but it will also work for PowerShell window, because the cloud shell shares the same storage account.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. The following command does it for one SSH session. Use this if you only want to do it once:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user host.net
```

If you want to do it for all SSH sessions here on out (I don't recommend this!), use a *SSH config file*

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Comment: I'm using commands mentioned in your answer but getting errors as given in screenshot in question. Can you guide me how to use those commands.

Comment: The second half are not commands - they are contents inside a *SSH config file* located in your home directory in `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Can I find it in Azure Linux VM settings.Where physical file exists. I can't login to linux machine.

Comment: Finally I set setting StrictHostKeyChecking value to no but now I'm getting error as given in update 2 in question. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Remove the known_hosts file